# How can I use Maven to specify which Junit @Category of tests to run without needing to specify the full path of each category?

Tags: java, maven, junit, categories, maven-surefire-plugin

I'd like to use Maven to specify which tests to run using Junit @Category annotations, without needing to specify the full path of the categories.

Currently I specify which category of tests to run using the full path of the categories.

```
-Dgroups="com.example.categories.FastTests,com.example.categories.SlowTests"
```

I'm looking for a way to shorten that to:

```
-Dgroups="FastTests,SlowTests"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This example could help you - https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html and https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories

Comment: in the example under "Using categories with Maven", they write it as `<groups>com.example.FastTests,com.example.RegressionTests</groups>`

I was wondering if there's any way to avoid having to write **com.example.** before the category names

Comment: It could be achieved when, for example, FastTests and RegressionTests are present under src-> main -> java with no package.

Comment: You could use profiles- define a `slow` and a `fast` profile, place properties in those profiles to enable the tests, and then enable profiles calling `mvn .. -Pslow,fast`